# What are the .channels and .registry folders in the symfony /plugins folder?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am upgrading a Symfony website from 1.2.9 to 1.4.1 and having a lot of fun in the process (NOT!).

I have decided to clean up all unecessary files and folders and leave things to the bear minimum, in the process - since I had acquired a lot of plugins etc over a period of time - some of which were installed by PEAR and others (mostly), manually. Since I dont like using PEAR in any case, I will be installing all plugins manually hence forth (from now on).

As part of the cleanup process, I want to get rid of the /plugins folder. I suspect that these are to do with PEAR, but I dont know if symfony needs them to run. In my 1.4 website, I will be installing all the plugins that I (actually use) manually. So can I get rid of the following files (in /plugins) ?

```
.channels
.depdb
.depdblock
.filemap
.lock
.registry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes these are pear related. You can get rid of them. 
I'm doing the same move from pear to manual install.